# How to Insert a value/update the existing value with a new value for a single column in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Customers Table in my Rails application, with columns to store the customer details. Once the customer login/signup the basic details of that customer will be saved into this table columns. 
In the Customer table there is a **purchase_id** column which is blank by default. When a customer purchase something from my site, a purchase_id will be created as **@order.purchase_id**.
So once the purchase is done, I want to update the Customer Table with this 
@order.purchase_id like something the following:

```
@customer.purchase_id = @order.purchase_id
```

How to do this in my Customers controller ?
I want to save/update the customer table to store the purchase_id permanently in my table.

Comment: That seems straightforward. Where is the issue? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I didnt get any error, but the value is not getting updated in my database :(

Comment: >> Customer.last
  Customer Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers"   ORDER BY "customers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Customer id: 54, firstname: "Rose", lastname: "Davis", email: "rose@gmail.com", phoneno: "1234567890", created_at: "2016-01-04 09:13:30", updated_at: "2016-01-04 09:13:30", devicemodel_id: 2, middlename: "Mary", salute: "Mr.", user_id: 1, creater_id: 7, sale_type: "LEASE", referral_id: 7, purchase_id: nil>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the record.

```
@customer.purchase_id = @order.purchase_id
@customer.save!
```

or

```
@customer.update_attribute(:purchase_id, @order.purchase_id)
```

Comment: Thank , you let me try this :)

Comment: thank you :) 
@customer.update_attribute(:purchase_id, @order.purchase_id)
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

@Simone advice is perfect

use [update](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) also same like update_attributes

```
  Customer.update(@customer.id, :purchase_id => @order.purchase_id)
```

but better if you use the operation in model section it will be a good try

Or
In model customer,

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :order   
 after_save :purchase_update

 def purchase_update
    self.update_attribute(:purchase_id, order.purchase_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)